# Docker linking db container with spring boot and get environment variables

Tags: java, spring, docker, spring-boot

I have an springboot application container and mongodb container in docker.

```
docker run -p 27017:27017 -d --name myMongo mongo
```

So I'm running mongodb container first and after springboot container.

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 --name mySpringApp --link myMongo:mongodb mySpringApp
```

After that I want to get that environment variables in my springboot app.

```
MONGODB_PORT=tcp://172.17.0.5:27017
MONGODB_PORT_5432_TCP=tcp://172.17.0.5:27017
MONGODB_PORT_5432_TCP_PROTO=tcp
MONGODB_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT=27017
MONGODB_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.5
```

In application.properties file normally I have like that constant configuration for ip and port, so it connect mongodb container without any problem.

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=172.17.0.56
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
```

But in that application.properties file i there a way to get that environment variables , btw i tried  `#{systemEnvironment['MONGODB_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR']}` like this notation. But my app couldn't connect to mongodb container. Is there a way any good practise for this situation , also i tried to implement `AbstractMongoConfiguration` get systemEnvironment variables with `@Value` annotation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My advise is to discard the IP inside the environment variables and properties at all.

```
--link myMongo:mongodb
```

> Links myMongo container to host 'mongodb'. This manages docker inside your host config.

Now adjust your properties as follows:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=mongodb
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
```

> Now there is no need to manage IPs inside the container.

Comment: thanks for your advice, it works with this solution, but is there a way to solve my problem according to my approach?

Comment: I have read this http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html and I have to say that it is a little bit sketchy about environment variables. You can always go back calling System.getenv(). The Spring way is usually using EL-Expressions like ${MONGODB_PORT}. You can try this inside your property file and a Spring Boot External YAML file. If you use a dedicated Spring Property Loader then these expressions are being interpreted at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, btw I need a clarification ; docker resolves mongodb(like domain) as host , but it points which ip exactly?

Comment: Docker manipulates the host config of the container and adds the assigned ip address.  MongoDB is resolved inside the container.  Docker uses the Docker Ip Address and manages the network over its installed network adapter. Type docker inspect container | grep IPAddress in order to view the ip. Currently, if the ip changes, then also the linked container has to be restarted because mongodb will point to the old ip address.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, I want my code to still work fine in IntelliJ, when I run it locally. Is there any way I could do that ?

Comment: Simply add the hostname mongodb to you local host config, e.g. /etc/hosts and route it to your localhost. Furthermore, map the ports of your mongodb container to your local host, e.g. docker run -p 27017:27017. Afterwards your mongodb container is available in your intellij and inside Docker with the same port and hostname.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the IP and port on which your MongoDB is running, you can use the *inspect* command:

```
docker inspect myMongo
```

You'll get the IP and the port, which you can use directly without using --link command.

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=172.17.0.2 // for me mongo was running on this IP, check yours 
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
```