# Docker Java Image cannot connect to Docker Mongo

Tags: mongodb, docker, spring-boot

I'm getting timeout errors from my Java application (Spring Boot) that uses a MongoDB, the connection works when I run the jar, however when it is Dockerized, the connection times out. I'm not sure if I'm just not configuring something correctly with Docker?

Comment: How is the container connected to the MongoDb? using a host name or an ip? is the ip accessible inside the container using `nc` or `ping`?

Comment: I'm running both of these locally. The hostname is localhost since it's local. I'm not sure how to see if its accessible within a docker container.

Comment: use the command `docker exec -it {container_id} /bin/bash` do go inside the container. then run ping to your localhost's ip on your network (it is not 127.0.0.1) and see how it responds.

Comment: Seem to be getting responses for both localhost and local ip.

Comment: use curl on your mongo ip and port. see what you get as a result. install it using the package manager for your distribution if it not already

Comment: I'm getting a connection refused. Would it be possible that the port isn't open?

Comment: the port is open if you can access it on your localhost.If you want it to be accessible everywhere . bind it to `0.0.0.0` ip so you can access it from your container.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121762/discussion-between-joel-holmes-and-miad-abrin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `--link` docker run option to easily connect to your mongo container with your specified host name

Comment: Part of this was the answer, the other part was I needed to define the ip of the image then as outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31743006/5294769

Answer (score 0):

If your dockerized Spring Boot app is using 'localhost' to try to connect to the dockerized Mongo instance, it will fail because 'localhost' in that context refers to the container (the one running the Spring Boot app, which is not running Mongo).

If the name of your Mongo container is 'mongo' you can find the docker network IP address of that container with

```
$ docker inspect mongo | grep IPAddress
```

Then you should be able to configure your Spring Boot container to connect to mongo at that address.

Comment: There isn't an IP address